# CakePHP 2.0 Router::connect how to pass named params

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm rebuilding a site in CakePHP 2.0 and need to route some old URLs to new ones. For example, this:

http://www.example.com/widget/helpbox/location/mackay-qld

Will route to this:

http://www.example.com/widgets/answer/location_id:10542

In order to do this, I have the following route:

```
Router::connect(
    '/widget/helpbox/location/mackay-qld',
    array(
        'controller' => 'widgets',
        'action' => 'answer',
        'location_id' => 10542
    )
);
```

When I debug $this->request->params, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [plugin] => 
    [controller] => widgets
    [action] => answer
    [named] => Array
        (
        )

    [pass] => Array
        (
        )

    [location_id] => 10542
    [isAjax] => 
)
```

But I expect this:

```
Array
(
    [plugin] => 
    [controller] => widgets
    [action] => answer
    [named] => Array
        (
            [location_id] => 10542
        )

    [pass] => Array
        (
        )

    [isAjax] => 
)
```

I've also tried calling

```
Router::connectNamed(array('location_id'));
```

...but to no avail. location_id is still passed in the same way - not as a named parameter.

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: This could be a bug. Consider asking/reporting it for the Cake2 guys. http://ask.cakephp.org/ and http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard respectively.

Answer (score 1):

After filing a ticket and getting a response as the ticket being invalid, it forced me to dig a little deeper. I finally understand what needs to be done. Since the inbound URL does not contain the named parameter, the route connection cannot be made the way you are trying to do it. A route connection is used as a template on how to route certain locations to a new location. However, what you want to do is route a specific URL to a new one. What you are looking for is a redirect.

```
Router::redirect(
    '/widget/helpbox/location/mackay-qld',
    array(
        'controller' => 'widgets',
        'action' => 'answer',
        'location_id' => 10542,
    ),
);
```

That should return the results you are looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear! Mark Story set me on the right path by setting my bug to invalid. lol. But I am happy it works for you.